# Is there a way to use scrollbar element alone at xaml without ScrollViewer in uwp, like it did in wpf?

Tags: uwp-xaml

In wpf you could make the scrollbars to work similarly like slider without some contents to be scrolled. But in uwp as I've tried it seems impossible. Is there a way to use scrollbar element alone without the scrollviewer involved?

Comment: With my understanding, if you want to make the scrollbar work like the slider, why not use slider directly? What's the effect that you want to achieve?

Comment: Of course you could always use slider for that purpose in uwp, but still I'm curious that is there a way to achieve this with scrollbar like the case with wpf? And if that's not possible at all, then why is there a usable scrollbar element present at uwp xaml in the first place?

Comment: What's the final effect that you want to achieve?